# Is it possible to use app-only Graph API tokens with SharePoint REST API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-rest-api

On a project, I'm using app-only tokens and Graph API to perform various operations on data in Office 365 ([this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) is how the app is registered). When it comes to SharePoint, certain operations are not available through the Graph API but are available through SharePoint REST API.

My question is: is there a way to use Graph API tokens with SharePoint REST API?

The closest answer I could find is this:

> To access the http:///site/_api/lists endpoint, Graph API token wont work.

Taken from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220642/oauth-authentication-for-sharepoint-rest-api).

However, the answer is about a specific endpoint and is pretty old, so I wonder whether this is (still) true.

**Update**

[Here](https://github.com/hariso/sp-rest-api/blob/master/src/main/java/Main.java)'s how I'm calling the various endpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token you are using to access the graph is in fact an azure active directory token.  Lots of other APIs accept those in office 365.
The procedure is more or less the same expect instead of selecting the Microsoft graph API when requesting the scopes, you have to select the SharePoint API.
Also note that some actions (mostly the tenant related things) do require you to present a token generated with a client id + certificate and not client id +secret.

EDIT: if you are using AAD v2 endpoints the requested scope has to be `https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/.default` when requesting an access token for SharePoint REST API

Comment: Thanks baywet! I've tried doing that, but it keeps telling me that the scope is invalid. I'd be grateful if you could check out the code (here: https://github.com/hariso/sp-rest-api/blob/master/src/main/java/Main.java#L77-L84) and hint what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I know they are in the process of changing things but you don't need URLs for SharePoint scopes. Also as those are two different resources, you should make two different access token requests and not mix the scopes for different resources in a single request

Comment: Yup, I'm doing one token request per resource already (almost the same as in the sample code). However, putting Sites.ReadWrite.All as the scope only gives the same error.: / To be honest, the documentation and resource are quite confusing, and in some places I read that the URL is a must, whereas in other that it isn't.

Comment: Didn't see you were using v2 endpoints. Have you tried `https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/.default` ?

Comment: In fact I did, just a few minutes ago. And that does give a token. But when I try to use it with SPO REST API, it gives me a 401. But, that's at least one step forward!

Comment: refer to my original answer, in app only context, some endpoint only expect tokens generated from client id + certificate and not secret, this also could be better documented.

Comment: After some struggle to get the certificates working, I am able to use Graph API tokens with SPO REST API. Thanks for the help! Do you mind adding your comment about the scope (https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/.default) to the answer. I'll be glad to accept it.